# UITabBarController resets tab titles color for tabs after presenting new controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
   
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       welcomeNavigationController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple], for: .selected)
       createNavigationController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemOrange], for: .selected)
       settingsNavigationController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGreen], for: .selected)
   }
}
```

I have different colors for different titles in UITabBarController. The code below works at the beginning.

But after I present the new controller above and go back, the currently selected tab still has its unique color, but all others tabs have default system blue color. And even though **viewWillAppear()** calling again on coming back to the UITabBarController it doesn't paint titles to different colors again.

**So after presenting new controller above the TabBarController it reset all titles color except currently selected and it is impossible to paint them again even with delay.** How is it possible, how to fix it?

I don't have in my code any more places where I would change any attributes of UITabBar.

```
 navigationController.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

....

```
navigationController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found to date is to set the same TabBarItems again and again every time on viewWillAppear() which is I consider very stupid solution but still can't find anything else that would work.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let welcomeIco = UITabBarItem(title: R.string.localizable.collection(),
                                 image: R.image.collection_dis()?.withRenderingMode(.automatic),
                                 selectedImage: R.image.collection_act()?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
    welcomeIco.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple], for: .selected)
    welcomeNavigationController.tabBarItem = welcomeIco
    
    let createIco = UITabBarItem(title: R.string.localizable.create(),
                                 image: R.image.create_dis()?.withRenderingMode(.automatic),
                                 selectedImage: R.image.create_act()?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
    createIco.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemOrange], for: .selected)
    createNavigationController.tabBarItem = createIco
    
    let settingsIco = UITabBarItem(title: R.string.localizable.settings(),
                                   image: R.image.settings_dis()?.withRenderingMode(.automatic),
                                 selectedImage: R.image.settings_act()?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
    settingsIco.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGreen], for: .selected)
    settingsNavigationController.tabBarItem = settingsIco
}
```